# HttpRequest (PHP), how to post objects

Tags: php, http, post

code is as below:

```
<?php
//set up variables
$theData = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>php.net</to>
    <from>lymber</from>
    <heading>php http request</heading>
    <body>i love php!</body>
</note>';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/script.php';

//create the httprequest object                
$httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST, $options);
//add the content type
$httpRequest_OBJ->setContentType = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
//add the raw post data
$httpRequest_OBJ->setRawPostData ($theData);
//send the http request
$result = $httpRequest_OBJ->send();
//print out the result
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Now httprequest calls the script here:

```
http://www.example.com/script.php
```

Over there I want to access the object, so that I can manipulate the data and send it back:

```
$httpRequest_OBJ->setRawPostData ($theData);
```

---

but it does not work. I tried `$_POST['theData']`, but this only works if you use `$r->**addPostFields**(array('user' => 'mike', 'pass' => 's3c|r3t'));`

How can I access the object `$theData`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are after is [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

So you can get the whole lot of XML that you posted like this:

```
$fp = fopen('php://input','r');
$data = '';
while (!feof($fp)) $data .= fread($fp,1024);
// $data should now contain the XML posted in your example
```

As a side note, I think the line

```
$httpRequest_OBJ->setContentType = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
```

...should probably just read

```
$httpRequest_OBJ->setContentType = 'text/xml';
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I place this segment of code. $fp = 

fopen('php://input','r');
$data = '';
while (!feof($fp)) $data .= fread($fp,1024);
// $data should now contain the XML posted in your example

and fopen('php://input','r'); , what do I replace 'php://input' with?

Comment: In `script.php` - i.e. at the server side, where you have sent the request to (and where you want to access the data). If you run that segment of code, `$data` should be identical to `$theData` at the client side. You don't replace `php://input` with anything - it is the input stream to access the raw POST body.

Comment: Thanks worked, XML tags seemed to have been stripped off, is there anyway of keeping them? And secondly, how can I get the server to send me the object back automatically say after its passed through a function and then access it in the original script? I know you can do this     //echo $r->send()->getBody();
    $test = $r->send()->getBody();
    echo $test; if you are not using raw POST body

Comment: As far as the tags being stripped off goes - how do you know this has happened? Are you sure it's not just that the browser renders them instead of printing them? And the second part - I'm not quite sure what your asking/what you want to do?

Comment: Nevermind, tags have not been stripped, my mistake :)

Say I append a string to $data like this in the script on the server side: 

while (!feof($fp)) $data .= fread($fp,1024);
$test="blabla";
$data = $data.$test;

but what I want to do now is after that is done to send the string back to the client based script (which initiated the original http request) so I can access it and modify it further from the client end. How do I do this? Can I modify my script on the client side to see if the object sent returns something? thanks

Comment: All you need to do to achieve that is `echo` or `print` the `$data`. So after you have finished manipulating the data, call `echo $data;` then at the client side, `$result` should contain a [`HttpMessage`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/class.httpmessage.php) object. So you you can get the manipulated data into a variable by calling `$response = $result->getBody();` - $response should now contain the manipulated data at the client side.